# yum list *php* on Centos 6.6 is not showing any php packages

Tags: php, linux, centos

`yum list *php*` was not showing any packages.  using yum update, the CentOS server went from version 6.3 to 6.6, but i still don't see any php packages with `yum list *php*`

yum repolist is showing:

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: p3plmirror02.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
 * epel: dl.fedoraproject.org
 * extras: p3plmirror02.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
 * remi: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * remi-php55: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * remi-safe: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * updates: p3plmirror02.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
remi
remi-php55
base
epel
extras
remi
remi-php55
remi-safe
updates

what have I messed up? where are the php packages?

Comment: Installing third party software is  [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
[unix.se] would be a more appropriate site for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found this from googling: the php packages were excluded in /etc/yum.conf.  I just edited the line that starts with exclude= and removed php* from that list.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the search in single quotes:

```
yum search '*php*'
```

Otherwise, your shell will try to expand the stars to mean files matching that pattern.

Comment: In bash, it worked correctly for me unquoted as `yum list *php*`